# Google Analytics, Tracking multiple values stored in an object

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, tracking

I'm currently creating an app that lets the user play multiple musical instruments. I use ajax to pass an object of instrument names and timestamps to a PHP function that then creates an mp3. My problem arises when trying to process this object and use the data to track which instruments were used, and how many times each was used. There are 15 instruments and I loop through the obj (using jquery) and fire one event per instrument. The reason I don't track the events live is that responsiveness is essential to the smooth running of the app and the event tracking can be expensive thus reducing responsiveness.

Once around 10 of the events have fired I start to get 'Exceeded maximum hit rate. Aborting hit'. (using the GA chrome extension to debug)

Has anyone out there had any similar issues processing events from an array like this? The only progress I've made is when I add a large delay on the loop but this is not ideal for obvious reasons.

P.s. The tracking code syntax etc is working fine as I use 1 function to process all of my tracking events and everything else is working with no issues

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at this previous Stack question:

[Google Analytics Event Tracking - Minimal Interval between the events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537523/google-analytics-event-tracking-minimal-interval-between-the-events)

You will need to familiarise yourself with the use limits of Google Analytics. I also suggest you check out the sampling documentation:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsSampling.html

This explains the limitations in reporting once you have the data in.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this definitely is the most unusual use case for GA that I've ever heard of. :)

I can't say anything specific about their rate limits, but I'm not sure whether this is a good fit for Google Analytics in the first place. I wouldn't hold it against them if they started blocking requests coming in at this rate.

Maybe it's worth taking a look at a self-hosted analytics suite like [Piwik](http://piwik.org) instead? I can't promise it can track things the way you currently try to do with GA, but it's a good product, aims to be direct competition to GA, and has a good support forum.

Comment: I'll take that as a compliment, however the idea to use GA for this was not my own.... I am aware of the limitations of GA but wondered if there were any neat work arounds for my specific situation. My pick would be to use piwik or my own custom analytics, unfortunately this is not an option. Thanks anyway!